# How to integrate wrapbootstrap theme into asp.net web site in visual studio 2013?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, twitter-bootstrap-3, themes

I am new to bootstrap. I downloaded a wrapbootstrap theme and is trying to include that in my website. In the downloaded theme, there are several folders under a folder called assets, like bootstrap, css, js, icons, img. Under bootstrap folder there are again subfolders called css, fonts and js. Can anyone please tell me where exactly in the project should i add these files? In case of a simple theme, I know we need to add the bootstrap css under Content folder and the bootstrap js under Scripts folder and we need to add it in BundleConfig.cs. But here, since there are different css files and js files, where can I include them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Where the files are located is really irrelevant so far as your application is concerned. The `~/Scripts` and `~/Content` folders are just a default convention that Visual Studio uses with the templates.

However, **nothing is preventing you from moving them**. When working with a template, you have one of two choices.

1. **Leave the files as they are**, and simply reference them, or include them into bundles in the paths they are located in.
2. Determine which CSS and JS files you need, and **re-shuffle everything to suit your particular projects needs**.

The first option makes it easier to upgrade the template in the future, while the second option makes your project files more coherent because they follow a similar structure.

At the end of the day though... **it's all just a resource location for you web server to resolve**. Do whatever makes sense for your project.